# Amazon S3 CLI Grants Options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

In the AWS S3 Console, you can grant permission to files for "Any Authenticated AWS User" and give "Open/Download" permissions.

What is the CLI command to do the same?

I already know the cp command (for uploading):

```
aws s3 cp filename s3://bucket/folder/filename
```

But, I can't figure out the --grants configuration and the documentation is not specific with the accepted values.

Bonus if you can provide the rest of the accepted values for the --grants flag (e.g. View Permissions, Edit Permissions)?

Can this be done recursively?

**EDIT 1**
I've found the following, however it makes the file available to EVERYONE (public).  So, where is the URI for my groups?  I'm assuming it's not the same as the group's ARN.

```
aws s3 cp file.txt s3://my-bucket/ --grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
```

We can alternatively do:

```
aws s3 cp file.txt s3://my-bucket/ --grants full=emailaddress=user@example.com
```

That will provide full rights to the account associated with that email address.

Still nowhere to mirror "Any Authenticated AWS User" (I am assuming this is authenticated within my account).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the `--acl` parameter to get the canned permissions:

```
aws s3 cp local.txt s3://some-bucket/remote.txt --acl authenticated-read
```

The documentation for [aws s3 cp](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html) describes what the shorthand syntax is for the CLI:

> --acl (string) Sets the ACL for the object when the command is performed. If you use this parameter you must have the
>   "s3:PutObjectAcl" permission included in the list of actions for your
>   IAM policy. Only accepts values of private, public-read,
>   public-read-write, authenticated-read, bucket-owner-read,
>   bucket-owner-full-control and log-delivery-write. See [Canned ACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl)
>   for details

`--grants` appears to allow fine-tuned custom ACLs, but the syntax is more complicated, as you discovered.

Comment: Is there a way to use --acl to allow AuthenticatedUsers read and write permissions?

Comment: I believe you would have to use the `--grant` option as @helloV describes, adding a write permission.

Comment: Thanks, --acl authenticated-read worked, can't believe I missed it.

Answer (score 6):

Check this link: [Using High-Level s3 Commands with the AWS Command Line Interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)

You may want to do:

```
aws s3 cp filename s3://bucket/folder/filename --grants read=uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
```

For recursive, use --recursive option

> When the --recursive option is used on a directory/folder with cp, mv,
>   or rm, the command walks the directory tree, including all
>   subdirectories. These commands also accept the --exclude, --include,
>   and --acl options as the sync command does.

Comment: Pretty sure that makes it public.  I want it available to all of my users associated with my account.